# Compare only same PlayerId in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i compare only same PlayerID from first select with PlayersIds from other select ?

```
select PlayerId ,
       sum([RedeemedAmount])
FROM table1
group by PlayerId
order by playerid

select playerid,
       sum(RedeemedBonusMoneyGrossWinAmount),      
       sum(BonusMarketingCostAmount)-sum(RedeemedBonusMoneyGrossWinAmount),
       sum(RedeemedBonusCashAmount)
FROM table2
group by PlayerId
order by playerid
```

Results from table1 are

```
PlayrID REdeemedAmount
    -1  0.000000
    1136    0.000000
    1145    216.000000
    1147    368.000000
    1148    108.000000
    1155    0.000000
```

Results from table2 are

```
PlayerId    value1      value2      RedeemedBonusCashAmount
    1136    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    1145    0.000000    216.000000  216.000000
    1147    -180.000000 368.000000  368.000000
    1148    50.000000   108.000000  108.000000
    1177    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    1188    0.000000    188.000000  188.000000
    1198    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Inner join

```
select *
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.PlayerId=t2.PlayerId
```